# Brain tree SDK update

Tags: magento2.2, payment-methods, braintree

Braintree suggesting to upgrade the SDK file. Is that necessary for Magento 2.2.x version?

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/best-practices/php

Magento not released any patches for this payment SDK update. Is that necessary to do this update?

Comment: Have you found any solution? If Yes, please share the solution.